# My variable refused to display in my Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

The country is changing along side the shipping. I could alert my shipping but will refuse to display in my div. What could be wrong? All calculations working well and displays well except for the `#usashipping` please help. My country changes and give the correct value for the calculation. The shipping fee just will not display.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

<script type="application/javascript">
var price= "";
var userprice="";
var flpay='';
var total='';
var shipping='';
var fees=30.0;

$('#country').change(function() {
var input = $(this).val();
var shipping;
if (input == 40) {
shipping = 10.0;
  $('#usashipping').html('10.0');

} else if (input == 236) {
shipping = 10.0;
  $('#usashipping').html('10.0');

} else {
shipping = 30.0;
  $('#usashipping').html('30.0');

}
if(fees=='') {
$('#fees').html(30); 
}
if(flpay=='')
 {
 $('#flpay').html(2*19.99); 
 }
 if(total=='')
 {
 var tot=19.99*2.0 +30.0 + shipping;
 var total= tot.toFixed(2);
  $('#total').html(total); 

   }
   $('.add').click(function() { 
    var $input = $(this).next();
    var currentValue = parseInt($input.val());

    var newinput= currentValue + 1;
    $('#gems').val(newinput);

    (newinput);
    if(newinput==1)
    {
     var np1=(19.99*2.0);
     flpay= np1.toFixed(2);
     $('#flpay').html(flpay);

     var tot= (fees + shipping + flpay);
     var total= tot.toFixed(2);
     $('#total').html(total);

    var newp=19.99;
    var price= newp.toFixed(2);
     $('#price').html(price); 
     useprice= 19.99;  
     }

    else if(newinput>1) 
     {
     //useprice=useprice;
    var newprice= 19.99 + (9.99*(newinput-1));
    var np1 =(2*newprice);
    var flpay = np1.toFixed(2);

    $('#flpay').html(flpay); 
    var tot =( fees + shipping + (2*newprice) );
    var total= tot.toFixed(2);
    $('#usashipping').html(shipping);       
    $('#total').html(total);
    var newp= newprice.toFixed(2);
    $('#price').html(newp);    
    }
    // newprice= price * 2;
    // $('#price').html(newprice);

    });


  <!-- language: lang-html -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
     </script>

      <div>
        First &amp; Last Months Payment = $<span data-first-last-month-fees="" id="flpay"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        Shipping Fee = $<span data-shipping-fee="" id="usashipping"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        Total due today : $<span data-total-due="" id="total"></span>
      </div>
```

Comment: try to use `replaceWith` see this [doc](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Comment: Try alerting "input" at the beginning of the change function so you see wether it's actually called correctly

Comment: I tried with your given markup and it is working fine for me.

Comment: I can alert my input, it displays the figure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work perfectly, but there are few things that you could improve in your code:

- Instead of declaring `shipping` variable 3 times in each condition, you need to declare it only once, then update it in each condition, and make sure it's stored as a string so it can be displayed correctly in your HTML.
- Instead of updating the HTML content of your `span` in every condition, just update it with the `shipping` amount in the end.

This is how should be your code:

```
$('#country').change(function() {
  var input = $(this).val();
  var shipping;
  if (input == 40) {
    shipping = '10.0';
  } else if (input == 236) {
    shipping = '20.0';
  } else {
    shipping = '30.0';
  }
  $('#usashipping').html(shipping);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('#country').change(function() {
  var input = $(this).val();
  var shipping;
  if (input == 40) {
    shipping = '10.0';
  } else if (input == 236) {
    shipping = '20.0';
  } else {
    shipping = '30.0';
  }
  $('#usashipping').html(shipping);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="236">236</option>
<option value="100">100</option>

</select>
<div>
  Shipping Fee = $<span data-shipping-fee="" id="usashipping"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It still doesnt display my shipping fee

Comment: Gosh! my code still not working, the shipping wont just display........Help!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can see error showing in your code. I found "`$('.add').click`" inside "`$('#country').change`". Also "`$('#country').change`" function you declared local variable "`var shipping;`" that's why no change on global "`shipping;`" value but you using it inside "`$('#country').change`" function. I modified little bit now try with following code and comment reply if not work for you:

```
var price= "";
var userprice="";
var flpay='';
var total='';
var shipping='';
var fees=30.0;

$('#country').change(function() {
var input = $(this).val();
if (input == 40) {
    shipping = 10.0;
    $('#usashipping').html('10.0');

} else if (input == 236) {
    shipping = 10.0;
    $('#usashipping').html('10.0');

} else {
    shipping = 30.0;
    $('#usashipping').html('30.0');

}

if(fees=='') {
    $('#fees').html(30); 
}

if(flpay=='')
{
    $('#flpay').html(2*19.99); 
}

if(total=='')
{
    var tot=19.99*2.0 +30.0 + shipping;
    var total= tot.toFixed(2);
    $('#total').html(total); 

}
})

$('.add').click(function () {
var $input = $(this).next();
var currentValue = parseInt($input.val());

var newinput = currentValue + 1;
$('#gems').val(newinput);

(newinput);
if (newinput == 1) {
    var np1 = (19.99 * 2.0);
    flpay = np1.toFixed(2);
    $('#flpay').html(flpay);

    var tot = (fees + shipping + flpay);
    var total = tot.toFixed(2);
    $('#total').html(total);

    var newp = 19.99;
    var price = newp.toFixed(2);
    $('#price').html(price);
    useprice = 19.99;
}

else if (newinput > 1) {
    //useprice=useprice;
    var newprice = 19.99 + (9.99 * (newinput - 1));
    var np1 = (2 * newprice);
    var flpay = np1.toFixed(2);

    $('#flpay').html(flpay);
    var tot = (fees + shipping + (2 * newprice));
    var total = tot.toFixed(2);
    $('#usashipping').html(shipping);
    $('#total').html(total);
    var newp = newprice.toFixed(2);
    $('#price').html(newp);
}
// newprice= price * 2;
// $('#price').html(newprice);

})
```

Comment: I tried it all but still not working, maybe i shud post more of the markup.

Comment: Pls kindly check the update of the post. Thanks so much for ur help.

Comment: Also, my + and - buttons works well but when using -ive back from 3,2,1 the figure doesnt change from 2 to 1.

Comment: Somebody should pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

I only changed the div id from `#usashipping` to something else and it works just fine. Maybe `#usashipping`is now a constant in jquery library.